# Windows 10: Batch file to change system wide language?

Tags: windows, batch, language

How to change language in Windows 10 by single click?

By doing it manually this tutorial works https://www.windowscentral.com/how-properly-change-system-default-language-windows-10 except

A. No need to add laguage in step 4. because needed language already added.

B. In step 6. "Set default" button is grayed out. This setting is done in step 11 by clicking Options.

Windows 10 is installed normal way. In installation local language is set but Windows 10 is still all English. Changing the language by manually is slow and requires booting.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689831/change-regional-and-language-options-in-batch

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the reg under `HKCU\Control Panel\International`

You can do `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International"` to see what values are in here

Im not the best with reg.exe so you'll have to do something like:
 `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v "value" /d "data" /f`